# Find cell by your position on cells total in a 2D array

Tags: excel

I need find determined cell position based in yout position of range cells total.

Example:

[image]

In this table, i have 15 cells,"x" is 8th in these 15 cells and your position is B3. I need find B3 knowing only "x" is 8th cell in this range using a formula.

How to make a formula to find cell this way?

Comment: are you providing the `8` or do you find the cell that has `x` and return its address?

Comment: I provide the 8. The "x" is just to illustrate the cell I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a 3 column wide area:

```
=ADDRESS(INT((F1-1)/3)+1,MOD(F1-1,3)+1)
```

Where F1 has the `8` and the `3`s represent the number of columns in the area.

[image]

Comment: wow, this works! But how this works without a range? If I want to provide "A:C" or a:1:c5, is it possible?

Comment: If you always start at A1, you only need to change the `3`s to the number of columns.  If it does not start at A1 then you change the `3`s to the number of columns and the first `+1` to the starting row and the second `+1` to the starting column.  If you want to truly reference a range: `=ADDRESS(INT((F1-1)/COLUMNS(A1:C5))+MIN(ROW(A1:C5)),MOD(F1-1,COLUMNS(A1:C5))+MIN(COLUMN(A1:C5)))`

Comment: Now if your true final intention is to return the value in that cell and think I will just wrap it in INDIRECT, that is the long way around.  You could simply do: `=INDEX(A1:C5,INT((F1-1)/COLUMNS(A1:C5))+1,MOD(F1-1,COLUMNS(A1:C5))+1)`  Then just change the references and it will pick the value at the number you desire.

Comment: I just need find cell by its position, made some adjustments on your answer and it's working perfectly! thanks!